# Polynomial Graph Isomorphism from Star System Reconstruction?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, isomorphism-testing

Confusion is possible, but two papers and a simple graph
transformation imply Graph Isomorphism is polynomial, which
is an open problem.

The closed neighborhood of a vertex in a graph is sometimes called the “star”
of the vertex. The “star system” of a graph is then the multi-set of closed
neighborhoods of all the vertices of the graph and the Star System problem
is the problem of deciding whether a given system of sets is a star system of
some graph

According to [paper1 p.20](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/research/tr/1977/CS-77-04.pdf) reconstructing the graph from its star system is GI-complete.

According to a [paper2 p.3 On the Complexity of Reconstructing H-free
Graphs from their Star Systems](https://sites.cs.ucsb.edu/~daniello/papers/StarSystem.pdf), $C_4$-free or $C_3$-free graphs can be reconstructed from their star systems.

There is isomorphism preserving graph transformation (given in paper1) 
$G \to G'$ where $G'$ is chordal and hence $C_4$ free.
The transformation is $V(G')=V(G) \cup E(G)$. In $G'$ add a clique
of $V(G)$ and for $u,v \in E(G)$ add the edges $((u,v),u),((u,v),v)$.
$G'$ is $C_4$-free, chordal and split.

For $C_3$-free graph just take the subdivision of $G$,
which is bipartite and triangle free.

> Does this prove GI is polynomial?

Comment: The problem is not about reconstructing a graph from its stars, but of determining whether *any* graph has a given multiset of stars.  Note that lots of graphs have the same multiset of stars without being isomorphic.